# String split, Token indexing and concatenation (in this order)

Tags: mysql

How to split the string and create a word with the first character of each token? I use MySQL 5.7 .

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
   id_ INTEGER  NOT NULL,
   value1 INT NOT NULL
INSERT INTO t1 (name) VALUES
('Dummy Gummy 1'), ('Dummy 2'), ('Dummy 3'), ('Dummy 4'),
('Dummy 5'), ('Dummy 6'), ('Dummy 7'), ('Dummy 8')

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS result (
   id_ INTEGER  NOT NULL,
   value1 INT NOT NULL
INSERT INTO result (new_name) VALUES
('DG1'), ('D2'), ('D3'), ('D4'),
('D5'), ('D6'),('D7'), ('D8')
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Vérace you don't work very often with marketing people, do you? They make a lot of challenging questions to summarize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are not a strong suit for RDBMS, in your case a function is the best.

Here the rules are simple: split the text, check if it is a number then add the number to the result, if not take the first Letter.

If your rules get more complicated, you have to expand the part after `IF item <> '' AND item IS NOT NULL THEN`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
>    id_ INTEGER  AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
>    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
>    
> INSERT INTO t1 (name) VALUES
> ('Dummy Gummy 1'), ('Dummy 2'), ('Dummy 3'), ('Dummy 4'),
> ('Dummy 5'), ('Dummy 6'), ('Dummy 7'), ('Dummy 8')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE Function getfirsst(_text VARCHAR(100))
> RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
> DETERMINISTIC
> BEGIN
> DECLARE inipos INTEGER;
> DECLARE endpos INTEGER;
> DECLARE maxlen INTEGER;
> DECLARE item VARCHAR(100);
> DECLARE result VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';
> DECLARE delim VARCHAR(1);
>
> SET delim = ' ';
> SET inipos = 1;
> SET _text = CONCAT(_text, delim);
> SET maxlen = LENGTH(_text);
>
> REPEAT
>     SET endpos = LOCATE(delim, _text, inipos);
>     SET item =  SUBSTR(_text, inipos, endpos - inipos);
>     IF item <> '' AND item IS NOT NULL THEN
>         IF item REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN
>             SET result :=  CONCAT(result,item);
>         ELSE
>             SET result :=  CONCAT(result,LEFT(item,1));
>         END IF;
>         
>     END IF;
>     SET inipos = endpos + 1;
> UNTIL inipos >= maxlen END REPEAT;
> RETURN result;
> END
> ```

> ```
> SELECT getfirsst(name) FROM t1
> ```
>
> ```
> | getfirsst(name) |
> | :-------------- |
> | DG1             |
> | D2              |
> | D3              |
> | D4              |
> | D5              |
> | D6              |
> | D7              |
> | D8              |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e16bfaacfc3f05b18a312207a8af35a)*

Comment: In my opinion, since column inputs are strings, the number-regex clause may be spared.

Comment: the problem i saw was with numbers bigger than 9 and i thought you wanted the hole number, but now you have a start to improve the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS result (
    id_ INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    value1 INT NOT NULL )
SELECT id_, CONCAT(LEFT(value1, 1), id_)
    FROM t1;
```

(and please provide a `PRIMARY KEY`)

Comment: I added a column called `name` to table t1 and `new_name` to table `result`. I hope my intentions are clear now.